# Mixed ASP.NET and classic ASP project slow performance

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp-classic, windows-10

I have a legacy Classic ASP web application that performs slowly on my current Windows 10 / SQL Server 2017 Dev machine as well as a Windows server 2016 machine.

In more detail, the ASP parts of the application construct and execute a lot of queries on the SQL server behind it. The queries seem to be taking about 5-10 seconds each to execute and some parts have more than 200 queries resulting in script timeout errors.

The interesting thing is that the same code ran on another Windows 10 Dev machine and performed just fine (the main difference is Windows defender being turned off on that machine), as well as on Windows server 2008.

I've tried disabling real time protection as well as Windows defender altogetger on my Dev machine with no luck.

Any ideas or hint as to what could be causing this?

Comment: First your should isolate the problem, *SQL Server*, *IIS* or *SO*. Try to perform a profile with *SQL Server* and discover if it's really spending a lot of time to execute the queries depending on the environment

Comment: @RicardoPontual I've done that. SQL Profiler shows that each query takes roughly 5000ms to execute. In more detail, the "Audit Logout" action right after the query is the one that displays the specified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the very undocumented `(local)` value for the database source was what was causing the delays. Changing `(local)` to the actual machine's name in your Classic ASP project's configuration will fix the issue. This is usually found in a some ASP configuration file within your project (e.g. `config.asp`).

I will edit this answer with several other topics that I found throughout my research which should apply to anyone having issues with Classic ASP projects.

What's also interesting and hasn't been answered yet is that two machines with (basically) the same stack were having different results.